# Laravel Route errors when filters are applied

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add authentication into my Laravel app. Users can log in just fine, but I want to ensure that anyone who goes to a page is logged in - I don't want someone to bookmark a page within the application and go to it without ensuring they're logged in.

As such, I've been looking into Filters. I must not be implementing it right, because I get the following error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given` when I go to one of the routes I've added the filter to, or any page that links to a filtered route.

Routes.php

```
Route::get( '/admin/login',          'UserController@getAdminLoginForm');
Route::get( '/admin/races',          array('before' => 'auth', 'RaceController@getAllRacesView'));
Route::get( '/admin/geographies',    array('before' => 'auth', 'GeographyController@getLocalGeographiesView'));
Route::get( '/admin/candidates',     array('before' => 'auth', 'CandidateController@getAllCandidatesView'));
```

Filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('/admin/login');
});
```

I had the pages working prior messing around with filters, so what am I missing about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the documentation says about adding a filter to controller actions:

> **[Attaching A Filter To A Controller Action:](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)**
>
> Route::get('user', array('before' => 'old', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));

So in short, you are missing the array key `uses`. Try something like this:

```
Route::get('/admin/races',    array('before' => 'auth', uses => 'RaceController@getAllRacesView'));
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right on the money. I must have undone that part when I was backing things up. I had it working originally for like...5 minutes and then I undid something and it quit working. Must have been that. Thank you so much!!